# I want to split a string after a period and put that sentence onto a separate line

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

I want to take user input then separate the string after each period. Then I want to put each sentence onto their own line in a text box in Visual Studio.

I know how to store the sentences in an array, and put each sentence on every other line but when I run, the outcome for every letter I type is `system.string[]`.

```
 string input = TextEditor.Text;
 string[] tokens = input.Split('.');
 Output.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
 Output.Text += tokens;
```

I am pretty sure it is coming from the `output.text = token;`, but I don't know what to replace that with. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string input = TextEditor.Text;
string[] tokens = input.Split('.');
Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tokens);
```

You can even achieve your goal within a single line

```
Output.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, TextEditor.Text.Split('.'));
```

or use string.Replace with (not sure if it is faster)

```
Output.Text = TextEditor.Text.Replace(".", Environment.NewLine));
```

Your current code fails because you add the array, not the individual string elements of the array. Instead string.Join joins the individual elements of the array with the separator specified as first parameter.

Remember however that to display multiple lines of text you need to have your textbox with enough height space and with the property Multiline set to True.

Comment: wow thanks! but i have an add on question. I also want it so that in the input, if you press the next line button (return) how do I make it so that it doesn't leave an empty line in output?

Comment: Please post a new question. This will give you more attention to your new specific problem

Comment: ok got it. But all in all thank you a bunch, you were great help!